# How to convert big numbers into word in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to convert big numbers like million,trillion etc into word, Please can any one help me regarding to this.

I have created a `function` which work fine but it work only for `9` digit number not working for more then 9 digits?

```
CREATE FUNCTION `number_to_string`(n INT) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET latin1 BEGIN
declare ans varchar(1000);
declare dig1, dig2, dig3,dig4,dig5,dig6,dig7,dig8,dig9 int;

set ans = '';
set dig9 = floor(n/100000000);
set dig8 = floor(n/10000000) - dig9*10;
set dig7 = floor(n/1000000) -(floor(n/10000000)*10);
set dig6 = floor(n/100000) - (floor(n/1000000)*10);
set dig5 = floor(n/10000) -  (floor(n/100000)*10);
set dig4 = floor(n/1000) -   (floor(n/10000)*10);
set dig3 = floor(n/100) -    (floor(n/1000)*10);
set dig2 = floor(n/10) -     (floor(n/100)*10);
set dig1 = n - (floor(n / 10)*10);
If dig9 > 0 then
case
        when dig9=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'One Hundred');
        when dig9=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Two Hundred');
        when dig9=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Three Hundred');
        when dig9=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Four Hundred');
        when dig9=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Five Hundred');
        when dig9=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Six Hundred');
        when dig9=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Seven Hundred');
        when dig9=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Eight Hundred');
        when dig9=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Nine Hundred');
        else set ans = ans;
    end case;
     if ans <> '' and dig8 =0 and dig7 = 0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' Million');
    end if;
    end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig8 > 0 then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
    end if;
    if dig8 = 1 then
    case
         when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans,'Ten Million');
          when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eleven Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans,'Twelve Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans,'Thirteen Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fourteen Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fifteen Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans,'Sixteen Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans,'Seventeen Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eighteen Million');
        when (dig8*10 + dig7) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans,'Nineteen Million');
        else set ans=ans;
        end case;
      else
      if dig8 > 0 then
        case
            when dig8=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
            when dig8=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
            when dig8=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
            when dig8=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
            when dig8=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
            when dig8=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
            when dig8=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
            when dig8=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
        if ans <> '' and dig7 =0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' Million');
        end if;
        end if;
         if ans <> '' and dig7 > 0 and dig8 =0 then
         set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
         end if;
         if dig7 > 0 then
         case
        when dig7=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One Million');
        when dig7=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two Million');
        when dig7=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three Million');
        when dig7=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four Million');
        when dig7=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five Million');
        when dig7=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six Million');
        when dig7=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven Million');
        when dig7=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight Million');
        when dig7=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine Million');
        else set ans = ans;
      end case;
      end if;
      end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig6 > 0 then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
    end if;

     if dig6 > 0 then
      case
        when dig6=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'One Hundred');
        when dig6=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Two Hundred');
        when dig6=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Three Hundred');
        when dig6=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Four Hundred');
        when dig6=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Five Hundred');
        when dig6=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Six Hundred');
        when dig6=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Seven Hundred');
        when dig6=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Eight Hundred');
        when dig6=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Nine Hundred');
        else set ans = ans;
    end case;
     if ans <> '' and dig4 =0 and dig5 = 0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' Thousand');
    end if;
    end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig5 > 0 then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
   end if;
   if dig5 = 1 then
    case
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans,'Ten Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eleven Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans,'Twelve Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans,'Thirteen Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fourteen Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fifteen Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans,'Sixteen Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans,'Seventeen Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eighteen Thousand');
        when (dig5*10 + dig4) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans,'Nineteen Thousand');
        else set ans=ans;
       end case;
    else
      if dig5 > 0 then
        case
            when dig5=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
            when dig5=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
            when dig5=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
            when dig5=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
            when dig5=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
            when dig5=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
            when dig5=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
            when dig5=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
        if ans <> '' and dig4 =0 then
        set ans=concat(ans, ' Thousand');
        end if;
    end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig4 > 0 and dig5 =0 then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
    end if;
    if dig4 > 0 then
    case
        when dig4=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One Thousand');
        when dig4=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two Thousand');
        when dig4=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three Thousand');
        when dig4=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four Thousand');
        when dig4=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five Thousand');
        when dig4=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six Thousand');
        when dig4=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven Thousand');
        when dig4=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight Thousand');
        when dig4=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine Thousand');
        else set ans = ans;
       end case;
      end if;
     end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig3 > 0 then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
     end if;
      if dig3 > 0 then
    case
        when dig3=1 then set ans=concat(ans, 'One Hundred');
        when dig3=2 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Two Hundred');
        when dig3=3 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Three Hundred');
        when dig3=4 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Four Hundred');
        when dig3=5 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Five Hundred');
        when dig3=6 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Six Hundred');
        when dig3=7 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Seven Hundred');
        when dig3=8 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Eight Hundred');
        when dig3=9 then set ans=concat(ans, 'Nine Hundred');
        else set ans = ans;
    end case;
end if;
if ans <> '' and dig2 > 0 then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
end if;
if dig2 = 1 then
    case
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 10 then set ans=concat(ans,'Ten');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 11 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eleven');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 12 then set ans=concat(ans,'Twelve');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 13 then set ans=concat(ans,'Thirteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 14 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fourteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 15 then set ans=concat(ans,'Fifteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 16 then set ans=concat(ans,'Sixteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 17 then set ans=concat(ans,'Seventeen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 18 then set ans=concat(ans,'Eighteen');
        when (dig2*10 + dig1) = 19 then set ans=concat(ans,'Nineteen');
        else set ans=ans;
    end case;
else
    if dig2 > 0 then
        case
            when dig2=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Twenty');
            when dig2=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Thirty');
            when dig2=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fourty');
            when dig2=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Fifty');
            when dig2=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Sixty');
            when dig2=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seventy');
            when dig2=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eighty');
            when dig2=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Ninety');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    if ans <> '' and dig1 > 0 and dig2 =0 then
    set ans=concat(ans, ' And ');
    end if;
    if dig1 > 0 then
        case
            when dig1=1 then set ans=concat(ans, ' One');
            when dig1=2 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Two');
            when dig1=3 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Three');
            when dig1=4 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Four');
            when dig1=5 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Five');
            when dig1=6 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Six');
            when dig1=7 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Seven');
            when dig1=8 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Eight');
            when dig1=9 then set ans=concat(ans, ' Nine');
            else set ans=ans;
        end case;
    end if;
    end if;

   return trim(ans);
   END
```

Please can any one help me,i want for big number like trillions and so on, Thank you

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: Consider doing this in the application code as SQL is not suited for this in general..

Comment: @RaymondNijland , I have created a function which convert number to word, I use for database purpose, i am using this in customize application.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter since your `n INT` has a maximum value of 2147483647.

Comment: Also i assume if you `select number_to_string(101)` the output should be  *"one hundred [and] one"* ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, its working , but only for millions, limit is just for `9` digits but not working for more then `9` digits,

Comment: @BillKarwin good point, i also increase size but not working,i have created function for millions for 9 digit but i don't know how to move forward for trillions and upto `9` digit number

Comment: Did you not write the code for the current function?

Comment: @BillKarwin no, i have just write for `9` digit and for millions and i don't know how for trillions and so on. I think need to add trillions and so on code in function.

Comment: Use [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) ? 64 bits number it's max should be 9223372036854775807 (UNSIGNED) -> nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six billion eight hundred fifty-four million seven hundred seventy-five thousand eight hundred seven  .. if you need bigger well you would have to simulate 128 bits numbers and calculations..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i also try `BIGINT` but it give me wrong result issue is not handle `trillions` and other so on in code, this is just for 9 digit and for millions , give me correct output for `9` digits but upto `9` digit give me wrong result

Comment: If it works for 9 digits, keep expanding your code for more digits using BIGINT datatype as input, using a different function names, such as INT-number-to-string and another for BIGINT-number-to-string to support the additional digits.

Comment: @WilsonHauck but i don't know ho to expand for more digits, i need this for 14 digits, but currently its working just for 9 digits, please can you help me?

Comment: You will NEED to name your existing procedure INT-number-to-string that works up to 9 digits.  Build a NEW procedure BIGINT-number-to-string to accomodate the higher values for the different DATA TYPES (capacities) and continue building your logic for the additional digits.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile with contact information.